# Difference between name keys in kubernetes yaml file

Tags: kubernetes

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: echo-job
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: echo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo
        image: busybox
        command: ['echo', 'Hello Kubernetes Jobs!']
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference between the following two fields:
`metadata: name: echo-job`
and
`spec: template: metadata: name: echo`

What do these two different values represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`metadata.name` is the name **of the job**.

`spec.template.metadata.name` is the name **of the pod created by the job** (which will also have a random suffix appended).

If I submit your manifest, we see the Job:

```
$ kubectl get job
NAME       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
echo-job   1/1           4s         14s
```

And we see the Pod created to run the Job:

```
$ kubectl get pod
NAME             READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
echo-job-q9jxq   0/1     Completed   0          51s
```

---

A single Job may end up creating multiple Pods if the Job fails. For example, if we replace your `echo` command with `["sh", "-c", "exit 1"]`, we might see:

```
NAME             READY   STATUS   RESTARTS   AGE
echo-job-2n9qt   0/1     Error    0          2s
echo-job-hw5wj   0/1     Error    0          22s
echo-job-n44ql   0/1     Error    0          33s
```